# java enums but like public static final int?

Tags: java

I want to have a list of constants like A, B, C related to integers 1, 2, 3

I know you can do like

```
class Example {
    public static final int A = 1;
    etc...
}
```

and

```
enum Example {
    A(1), ... etc;
    some initialization of an integer
}
```

But is there a way to do it like the public static final but as succinct as enums? When I use A and I really mean 1 I don't want to call Example.A.value or something like that.

Comment: variables in Enums are by default `public static final`

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Are you saying that `public static final int` is too long to type?

Comment: "I don't want to call `Example.A.value`" - you're in the wrong language for that. Unfortunately for you this comes with static typing and no user defined type coercion. You simply can't have an `enum` be or pretend to be an `int` at the same time.

Comment: Alright, thank you everyone and sorry. Can I scream new at this any louder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you want to do something like this:

```
enum Example {
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    ....
}
```

There is no nice simple syntax for this.

You either have to write out some constants:

```
public interface Example {
    public static final int A = 1;
    public static final int B = 2;
    ....
}
```

...Or you can add some other `value` to the enum:

```
public enum Example {
    A(1),
    B(2)
    ....

    private final int val;

    public Example (int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dave, So if you read my answer you can see that is exactly what I said.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use an interface, where variables are public, static and final by default:

```
interface Example {
    int A = 1;
    int B = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the shortest solution is:

```
public static final int A = 1, B = 2, C = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use Enum, then you can override **toString()** method in your enum, to get the value printed when you print your Enum Instance: -

```
enum Example {
    A(1), B(2);

    private int val;

    private Example(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
           switch (this) {
             case A:
                  return String.valueOf(val);

             case B:
                  return String.valueOf(val);

            }
            return super.toString();
    }
}

public class D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        Example a = Example.A;
        Example b = Example.B;

        System.out.println(a);  // Prints 1
        System.out.println(b);  // Prints 2
    }
}
```

**Ideally your above enum is just like the below class: -**

```
class Example {
    public static final int A = 1;
    public static final int B = 2;
}
```

So, I don't see the necessity of using Enums..